# VLOOKUP Returning #N/A Error

Tags: excel, formula

I have a VLOOKUP that searches for a value (Column A) on another worksheet by a value (Column L). When I try the VLOOKUP, I recieve an #N/A error.

This is the formula I have

```
=VLOOKUP(L3,'Unmet Projects Old'!A:BZ,1,FALSE)
```

Please could someone explain why this is incorrect?

Comment: Maybe it didn't find whatever you have in L3?

Comment: The `False` part of the formula is looking for an exact match.  If it does not find an exact match it will return the error.  If you are looking for a relative match and your data is sorted then remove the forth criterion or make it `TRUE`

Comment: Provide what value and type of Cell L3.

Comment: L3 is a text format that has '946109' in it. I have tried changing it to true and the same error occurs

Comment: If you go to `Unmet Projects Old` and search for 946109 can you confirm the value exists?

Comment: I the data in column A also in Text format?  If not you will get the error.  they both need to be numbers or text not either.

Comment: @ScottCraner have you found this an issue before? I often have sheets of mixed numbers and text and always finds them even crossed formats without errors.

Comment: I can confirm that the value exists and both columns are text format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` is working exactly as specified: if it can't find a match for the specified *lookup value* in the left-most column of the specified *lookup range*, it returns `#N/A`.

The second-to-last argument being a `1`, you're basically going to be returning the `946109` you have in `L3`, since the first column of your *lookup range* **must** contain the values you're looking up.

The last argument being `FALSE`, you're looking for an *exact match*. This is *usually* what you want when you use `VLOOKUP`.

Assuming the value you have in `L3` *does* exist somewhere in `'Unmet Projects Old'!$A:$A`, I'd suggest you look for:

- **Cells formatted as text**. These never play well with formulas. See if using the default "General" format fixes it.
- **Leading/Trailing spaces**, either in the lookup value (L3) or the lookup range; you can make your lookup value `TRIM(L3)`, and verify that the values in `'Unmet Projects Old'!$A:$A` don't contain any leading or trailing spaces. The lookup value must match *exactly*, and spaces count.

---

If the `1` is what you intend (i.e. you're looking up "ABCD" and expect "ABCD" to be returned), then the `#N/A` should also be expected (when the *lookup column* is 1, either you get the *lookup value* or #N/A).

If the `1` isn't what you intend, then `'Unmet Projects Old'!$A:$A` does not contain your *lookup value* and you need to adjust the `Unmet Projects Old` worksheet so that the value you're looking for exists in the **first column** of the *lookup range*.

If you can't have the *lookup value* in `'Unmet Projects Old'!$A:$A`, then you can't use a `VLOOKUP`. Consider using a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue was that the first column of the lookup range didnt contain the value I was trying to lookup. Thanks again :)